# Read state of non-global checkbox on next button click

Tags: inno-setup

I am customizing one of the Wizard Pages to add a few check boxes. I am adding the checkbox by calling `DesiredPageId := PageFromID(<wpXXX>)` and specifying `ChkBox.Parent := DesiredPageId`. Now, is there a way to access the state of such a check box in `NextButtonClick()` without having the checkbox control as global ?

I do see examples like the following but in those cases the control (Radio button / Checkbox) is global and hence accessible anywhere.

1. [Get radio button value [INNO SETUP]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20476219/get-radio-button-value-inno-setup)
2. [How can I add a CheckBox for optional files during install? (innosetup)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502346/how-can-i-add-a-checkbox-for-optional-files-during-install-innosetup)

One way could be to associate an `OnClick` function in which a state variable is updated (again, global) and the same is accessed in `NextButtonClick()`. Is there any other solution ?

Comment: What is wrong about using a global variable? If it limits you anyhow, you have to explain how and why.

Comment: In general, global variables make it a bit difficult to follow the code -- it can be read from / written to by any function and hence I try to avoid it as much as possible.