# How do I install files in the [Files] section if I've created my own components selection page instead of using the embedded one?

Tags: inno-setup

If I have created my own components selection page instead of using the `[Components]` and `[Types]` sections, how can I decide what files to install and when in the `[Files]` section?

Comment: @KenWhite I know how to use [Components] and [Files] sections. I meant that I created a custom page with my own controls on it instead of just adding the components to the [Components] section. By adding to the [Components] section those components will be placed on the SelectComponentsPage that I'm not using. So I can't use the Components parameter in the [Files] section anymore.

Comment: @KenWhite I have a couple of pages where I have to select components and I don't want all of them to be placed on one page. Also, I want my page to look different from the embedded one.
Here what it says in the manual:
**This section is optional. It defines all of the components Setup will show on the Select Components page of the wizard for setup type customization.**
I'm confused because I'm not using that page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14639971/62576 might help get you started. Or https://stackoverflow.com/q/50446128/62576

Comment: @KenWhite Oh, wow! I knew nothing about the **Check** parameter that I can use in the [Files] section. By using it I can omit the [Components] section at all. Thank you! You really helped.

Comment: I'm going to delete my previous comments (the ones without the links) to clean up some clutter. :-)

Comment: That does answer my question. Actually all the links are really helpful to me.Your help is appreciated!